# How to retrieve Gnome Online Accounts information (like Geary) for an email client in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, email, gnome

Currently I am building an email client in Python using gnome builder and libadwaita and I want to retrieve Gnome Online Accounts information for the user. I know Geary email client retrieves this information to access the user's emails, but I couldn't find any information on how to do it in Python.

Is there a Python library or module that can access the Gnome Online Accounts information? If so, how can I use it to retrieve the user's email credentials?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into https://github.com/chmouel/mongars should give you enough to get started.